# Replace character inside double curly brackets regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace `-` character with `_` inside a double curly brackets.

Example inputs:
`Hello {{first-name}}, how are you?`
`The event {{event-name-address}}`

Example outputs:
`Hello {{first_name}}, how are you?`
`The event {{event_name_address}}`

This is the regex I tried to do: `{{.+(-).+}}`, and this is the `preg_replace` PHP function I tried to use: `$template = preg_replace("{{.+(-).+}}", "$1_", $template);`

This doesn't seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Is `preg_replace('~{{[^{}]*\K-(?=[^{}]*}})~', '_', $template)` enough? Or can there be more than one hyphen in between `{{` and `}}`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Multiple hyphens are allowed.

Comment: You need `preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!^)|{{)[^{}-]*\K-(?=[^{}]*}})~', '_', $template)`

Comment: `-(?=[^{}]*}})` will match `-`s that are not between `{{...}}`. They must be only followed with `}}`, but the `{{` are not obligatory then.

Answer (score 2):

Curve brackets should be escaped, they are regex metasymbols. Than, use two groups for parts before and after the `-`:

```
(\{\{[^}]+)-([^}]+\}\})
```

and replace on `${1}_$2`.

`[^}]` is used to say "any symbol, but not `}`".

UPD: thank to @CarySwoveland for help with clarifying.

Comment: Does that work with multiple hyphens?

Comment: @demitt it throws this error: `preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '-'`

Comment: Yeap, in this case we have to use more specific part instead of `.` - for example, `[a-z]`. @CarySwoveland

Comment: Perhaps `(\{\{[^}]*)-([^}]*\}\})`, though it still matches just one hyphen between matching pairs of double-braces, but that may not be a problem. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CnKqPV/1)

Comment: Fully agree with @CarySwoveland in `[^}]` usage. But I think, we have to use it with `+` instead of `*` (just after), because we expect at least symbol before and after the `-`, don't we?

Comment: If at least one character is required fore and aft, yes, `+`. I changed `[^{}-]` to `[^{}]`, then, assuming pairs of double-braces could not be nested, changed it again to just `[^}]` (but include `{` or `-` does no harm). Remember that if a hyphen is included it needs to be at the beginning or end of the character class. As always, feel free to edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If double-braces are matched and not nested you can substitute matches of

```
(?<=[^{])\-(?=[^{}]+}})
```

with '_'. This assumes the hyphen between matched pairs of double-braces must be preceded by a character other than `'{'` and must be followed by a character other than `'}'`.<sup>1</sup>

Note this permits matching multiple hyphens with the the same matched pair of double-braces.

This relies on the assumption that if a hyphen is followed, after intervening characters that are neither open nor closed braces, by a pair of closing double-braces, that hyphen must be preceded by a pair of open double-braces, with intervening characters that are neither open nor closed braces.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0aGl6u/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follow:

```
(?<=      # begin a positive lookbehind
  [^{]    # match a character other than '{'  
)         # end positive lookbehind
\-        # match '-'
(?=       # begin a positive lookahead
  [^{}]+  # match one or more characters other than '{' and '}'
  }}      # match '}}'
)         # end positive lookahead
```

<sup>1. If this is not a requirement the expression can be simplified to `\-(?=[^{}]*}})`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!^)|{{)[^{}-]*\K-(?=[^{}]*}})~', '_', $template)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PziisU/2). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|{{)` - either the end of the previous match or `{{`
- `[^{}-]*` - zero or more chars other than `{`, `}` and a `-` char
- `\K` - match reset operator that omits the text matched so far from the memory buffer
- `-`  - a hyphen
- `(?=[^{}]*}})` - a location immediately followed by zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}}`.